# Magento 2.1 onepage checkout bug for every payment method a billing/shipping address

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

Maybe this is a bug in version 2.1

If I have e.g. 2 payment methods, after every payment method is the billing/shipping address shown (1 virtual item, so billing=shipping address).

So you would expect:

- billing/shipping address
- payment method 1
- payment method 2

But I get:

- payment method 1
- billing/shipping address + order button
- payment method 2
- billing/shipping address + order button etc.

For other itemtypes the same situation, so payment method 1, billing address + order button, payment method 2, billing address + order button etc.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal, but there is css to hide the sections that are not needed.

Are you including the standard magento css?

```
.checkout-payment-method .payment-method-content {
 display: none;
 padding: 0 0 20px 22px;
}
```

Plus other styles to show when active..

Comment: thanks these .css have been composed somewhere, that is all new for me and have to find out, in my case all have been shown ... I try now the default installation 2.1 with blank/luma theme to see if the problem is there too, there is nothing overwritten for this within my theme ..

Comment: yes in the luma theme it is going right, so there must be changed something within my theme ..

Comment: yes I fixed it for now, much style from styles-m.css (generated) was missing, but for now your piece of style and : .checkout-payment-method .payment-method._active .payment-method-content {
  display: block;
} was enough to repair it for me, now I am going to contact the template maker ..

Comment: Is it possible to disable the "billing and shipping address are the same" block in checkout?

Answer (score 4):

Every payment method gets to decide whether or not to show a billing address form at all, and if so, includes its own copy of it. Only one (for the currently-selected payment method) should ever be shown at a time. This is how it's supposed to work.

Comment: thanks you are right so my problem is why they are all shown ...